# Conflict updating to Rails 3.1.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am currently running one of my Rails applications on version 3.1.3. My gemfile always listed:

`gem 'rails', '3.1.3'`

This worked just fine. In an effort to move to 3.1.10, I changed my Gemfile to the following:

`gem 'rails', '~> 3.1.10'`

Surprisingly, things break when I run `bundle update rails` after that change:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "multi_json":
  In Gemfile:
    twitter (>= 0) ruby depends on
      multi_json (~> 1.3) ruby

    fnordmetric (>= 0) ruby depends on
      multi_json (1.2.0)
```

Just as a test, I tried changing the gem version to `'>= 3.1.0'` and that installed without any quims, albeit it went to 3.2, which I'm not ready for just yet on this particular application.

Any suggestions for getting this thing running on 3.1.10 which was released today to address a security vulnerability?

Also an update:

I am having absolutely no trouble stashing Gemfile.lock away and starting from Rails 3.1.4. As soon as I try to go to 3.1.5+, this is where all the trouble begins.

Comment: I am not familiar with this problem in particular, but you could alter the gemspecs for either oauth2 or rails so the multi_json dependency would no longer conflict. This would only work if multi_json didn't changing in an API-breaking way between its two versions...

Comment: How about "oauth2, "0.7.1"?

Comment: oauth2 0.7.1 and 0.8.0 both list their dep as "multi_json ~> 1.0", so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: yeah, I assume currently it is on `oauth2 (0.7.0)`. I'd suggest doing a full `bundle update`.

Comment: It also appears the twitter gem requires multi_json ~> 1.3. I'm not sure how this didn't break when I was running on 3.1.3. But it's painful right now when trying to update to 3.1.10.

Comment: @randombits Can you post your full Gemfile, please?  RubyGems says twitter requires "multi_json ~> 1.0", so that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Make the change in your Gemfile to

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.10'
```

Then try running

```
bundle update
```

instead of

```
bundle install
```

I can't see your Gemfile but this should will allow the bundler to try and find compatible Gem matches. If you have hard code a Gem revision you might have to relax it and repeat the update. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the gems, it appears that oauth2 lists "multi_json ~> 1.0" and ActiveSupport 3.1.10 lists "multi_json < 1.3, >= 1.0" as the dependencies, so that should resolve.  I've run into strangeness like this and fixed it by running

```
gem uninstall <relevant gems>
```

then running `bundle install` again.  So maybe try

```
gem uninstall oauth2 multi_json activesupport
```

then `bundle install`

#### Edit

```
gem uninstall twitter multi_json fnordmetric
```